# Conditional Probability/Axioms Of Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Question:

A student takes a multiple choice test with  20  questions. Each question has 5 possible answers, only one of which is correct.

a)If a student knows the answer to each question with probability  0.9 , what is the chance they will answer at least  14  correctly?

I am not sure how to go about this.

### What I have tried:

P(correct) = p(known) + p(unknown) x p(chosencorrect)

P(correct)= 0.9+ 0.1 x 0.2

P(correct) = 23/25

---

P(14) = 20C14 x (23/25)^14 (4/5)^6 (Option 1)

P(14) = 20C14 x (23/25)^14 (0.5/5)^6 (Option 2)

P(14) = 20C14 x (0.9/(23/25))^14 (4/5)^6 (Option 3 - employing conditional probability)

---

First time working with this, hence the errors.

Would someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: These attempts all appear to be looking at the question "find the probability that the student gets *exactly* $14$ right", which is not what was asked.  More to the point, the computations don't seem to be correct.  Where does $\frac 45$ come from, or $\frac {.5}{5}$?  You correctly compute $p=\frac {23}{25}$ as the probability that the student gets a given question right, which makes the probability that they get it wrong equal to $\frac 2{25}$.

Comment: The probability that a student choose the right answer at one question is just p(correct)=$0.9$. The fact that there are 5 possible answer does not affect the probability to choose the right answer.

Comment: @callculus42  I agree the question is poorly phrased and ambiguous as a result.  I read it as specifying that "the student is certain of the correct answer with probability $.9$ and in the remaining $10\%$ of cases the student guesses blindly, so has a $\frac 15$ chance of getting it right."  That appears to be consistent with the OP's approach (which, of course, doesn't make either of us right).   I agree that your interpretation is also possible.

Comment: I suggest:  work the problem with both interpretations (if you are using a program to do the computation, it should be an easy matter to toggle between the two readings).  Regardless of the interpretation, there are two sorts of approaches.  First, you can just compute the cases of exactly $14$, exactly $15$ and so on and add.  Second, you can approximate with a normal.  Either way, the success probability is so high that it would be strange to get fewer than $14$ right.

Comment: @lulu Yes, the question is open to interpretation.

Comment: @lulu Hey lulu :D, so was literally just brute forcing after a while because no matter what I tried it would not accept my q(probability of choice being incorrect). So to clarify, 4/5 for the questions where he did not know the answer and 0.5 for the ones where he did (1-0.9).

Comment: Right, but having computed $p=\frac {23}{25}$ you have taken all the information into account, so the probability of getting the thing wrong is $1-p=\frac {2}{25}$.

Comment: I tried (2/25)^6 as well. However this answer was not accepted either. I have recently started studying a masters in Data Science and this is my first week as part of the statistics course. I can do almost everything else but there are these odd questions that are a little misleading in certain paragraph as you can see.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist If a question is such poorly worded I would recommend to skip the question.

Comment: @callculus42 Will do. Tried your interpretation as well and that does not appear to be correct either.

Comment: Again, your computations are for *exactly* $14$ where the problem asked for *at least*  $14$.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist If I follow your interpretation the asked probability is $P(X\geq 14)=\sum\limits_{x=14}^{20} \binom{20}{x}\cdot \left( \frac{23}{25} \right)^{x}\cdot \left( \frac{2}{25} \right)^{20-x}\approx 99.94\%$

Comment: @callculus42  And with your interpretation, the $\frac {23}{25}$ is replaced by $\frac 9{10}$ (and of course the $\frac 2{25}$ is replaced by $\frac 1{10}$).  Either way, the probability of getting *at least* $14$ correct is over $.99$ so the question is very strange.

Comment: @lulu That is quite interesting. So the answer is: The chance is at least $99\%$.

Comment: @callculus42  As I say, I think it's weird.  Of course, as a computation it's a valid exercise (once the ambiguity is cleared up), but it's not really a sensible thing to look at.

Comment: @lulu  I agree .

Comment: @callculus42 I just learnt about the binomial cumulative distribution function. New to all of this. Will update you on the answer it eventually accepts.

Comment: @lulu OMW. Finally figured it out. The accepted answer is 0.9976 using CDF and 0.9 as my success rate.

Comment: @callculus42 See above. Incredibly annoying as to how misleading this was.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist Then my first interpretation was rhe right one.  Thanks for the reply..

Comment: @callculus42 Definitely. Thanks for the help and also clarifying the sum of part. I did not think to do that. This is all really easy once I have practised it. Do you perhaps know how I could go about using the CDF formula on a calculator or what the actual formula is itself. I cannot seem to find it for some reason. I ended up having to use a calculator on a website which is obviously not ideal.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist If you use a handheld calculator you can google the  instruction manual for this type of handheld calculator. For a given n and p the formula is $P(X\geq k)=\sum\limits_{x=k}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\cdot \left( p \right)^{k}\cdot \left(1-p \right)^{n-k}$. If the cdf of the binomial distribution is installed (only) then $P(X\geq k)=1-P(X\leq k-1)$. In your case $P(X\geq 14)=1-\underbrace{P(X\leq 13)}_{\textrm{cdf}}$. cdf with $p=0.9, n=20$ and $x=13$

Comment: @callculus42 Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist I had a typo. The right one is $P(X\geq k)=\sum\limits_{x=k}^{n} \binom{n}{\color{red} x}\cdot \left( p \right)^{\color{red}x}\cdot \left(1-p \right)^{n-\color{red}x}$. Replace $k$ by $x$. But I think the idea is clear. You're welcome.